# Android add View

Tags: android, android-layout, parent-child

I have the following problem:

The code below successfully adds my TextView to my custom RelativeLayout:

```
 RectF rectRecord = getItemRect(trCurrent);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this.getContext());
                 tv.setLeft((int)rectRecord.left);
                tv.setRight((int)rectRecord.right);
                tv.setTop((int)rectRecord.top);
                tv.setBottom((int)rect.bottom);

                addView(tv);
```

Unfortunately the methods ("setLeft,setRight,setTop,setBottom") aren't available on Android older than 3.0.
So I tried to add my TextView the alternative way:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins((int)rectRecord.left, (int)rectRecord.top, (int)rectRecord.right, (int)rectRecord.bottom);
                //tv.setLayoutParams(tv);
                addView(tv, params);
```

Doing it that way does not show a child control ...

I already tried to change the class my host control derives from ViewGroup to LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and the deprecated AbsoluteLayout but always the same.
Also removed my custom onDraw and onMeasure and "setWillNotDraw(false);" but that didn't solved my problem.

Snippet 1 is displaying my child views.
Snippet 2 does not show a child.
Can anyone point to the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your margins are set to 1234 - that's 1234 dip (density independent PIXELS) and that is huge. Your control doesn't show up on the screen because margins are too big, and your control has no place to show on the screen.

Comment: Ok,
actually 1234 is just a placeholder for this post...
I just need to know the difference between the first code snippet and the second one...
Since as mentioned above, the first snipped places my controls on screen and the second snippet doesn't...

Comment: adjusted my post so that you can see that there is a RectF returned which contains the coordinates ...